# akka eventbus - message guarantees - publish to bus guarantee

Tags: java, akka, actor, event-bus

I have looked everywhere, cant really get an information that I can base a concrete opinion on this.

Akka eventbus is only a "local facility"(to the jvm/node within cluster), and from what I have read:
messaging when it is done within the same jvm is far more reliable.

So, I I have eg producer A, B and C, and consumers X, Y and Z,:- 
if I produce message to topic that X is listening to, is X guaranteed to get this message (regardless of network reliability etc, if I publish to the bus, will it defiantly be "on the bus"?). I know for pub/sub it is at most delivery, but I cant find anywhere online that says the same for event bus. If I publish to the bus, will it be guaranteed to be on the bus? (ie if I send a message to a actor, I get no error if it doesn't arrive at the actor. But if I publish to an event bus, am I guaranteed that the event is on the bus, and if not is there an error raised?)

Answer (score 0):

The event bus doesn't really store anything except for a list of subscribers, publishing essentially just filters out the right receiving actors and posts the event to their mailboxes so the same delivery guarantees as for actor messaging applies (in short, at most once since the `Actor`, `ActorSystem` or JVM could stop/crash before the message has been processed by the subscribers).